# why doesn't work well mod_rewrite on hhvm in my server?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, hhvm

I'm using the **codeigniter** framework and **HHVM** server.
How do I write a legal URL for this?

My attempts continually return code 404 (page not found).

What's wrong with the following?

```
Server {
    Port = 80
    SourceRoot = /home/webroot
    DefaultDocument = index.php
}

VirtualHost {
    * {
        Pattern = .*
        RewriteRules {
            * {
                pattern = (.*)$
                to = index.php/$1
                qsa = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which web-server are you using?

Comment: `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` are both features of the Apache Webserver, if you aren't using Apache as webserver, remove the tags.

Comment: ok, because of i have needed to same function mod_rewrite in Apache webserver, used the tags

Comment: All the answers I find are to run HHVM behind nginx or apache and perform the routing through the other nginx or apache. That's very unfortunate. I still haven't found a suitable answer. Please let me know if you did.